# Crear un dataframe en base a dos ficheros ya existentes

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Poseo el siguiente fichero
`ficheros <- c("ventas_20160522_zaragoza.csv", "pedidos_firmes_20160422_soria.csv")`

Y quiero crear,mediante una función, un df  en el que posea las dos filas mencionadas y distribuidas en 3 columnas ("Nombre","Fecha","Provincia")

¿Cómo podría hacer eso?
No sé si la formula `strsplit()` funcionaría bien en este caso.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con el `split()` es que, por lo que se ve, hay un numero variable de separadores, por que el caracter aparece en el nombre también. Es un buen ejemplo para aplicar expresiones regulares:

```
df <- data.frame(Nombre = character(),
                 Fecha = character(),
                 Provincia = character())

df <- strcapture('(.+)[_](\\d+)[_](\\w+)', ficheros, df)
df

          Nombre    Fecha Provincia
1         ventas 20160522  zaragoza
2 pedidos_firmes 20160422     soria
```

Detalle:

- Usamos `strcapture()` para obtener los 3 "grupos" de datos
- Previamente hemos definido un `data.frame` vacío par completar los datos
- El patrón  `(.+)[_](\\d+)[_](\\w+)` define 3 grupos de captura (lo que encierran lo paréntesis) y representa, la primer parte hasta la fecha, la fecha y la última parte sin el `.csv`.

Desmembrando el patrón `(.+)[_](\\d+)[_](\\w+)`

- `.+`: Cualquier caracter un número ilimitado de veces
- `[_]`: Un guion bajo
- `\\d+`: Un caracter numérico un número ilimitado de veces
- `[_]`: Un guion bajo
- `\\w`: Un alfanumérico un número ilimitado de veces

Comment: Excelente!! Acabo de intentarlo y funcionó a la perfección. Tengo una breve consulta más. ¿Los términos dentro del paréntesis (.+) (\\d+) y (\\w+) tienen algún significado en particular en la definición de objetos?

Comment: Si, tienen un significado especial, en lo que hace a el matching mediante expresiones regulares, te agrego una explicación dentro de la respuesta